# Show that $f (z) = cz^n$ for some $c ∈ \Bbb C$ and $n ∈ N.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Suppose $f ∈ H (\Bbb C)$, $f (0) = 0,$ and
> {$z : |f (z)| < M$} is connected $∀ M > 0$
> Show that $f (z) = cz^n$
> for some $c ∈ \Bbb C$ and $n ∈ N.$

So I think it follows from the fact that $f(z)$ is bounded and entire for which it has a constant. Any hint or which theorem I can use to show this? I really tried to think of something but I only come with this that $f(z)$ is bounded but how exactly to show that it is $f (z) = cz^n$?

Comment: The given hypotheses certainly don't imply that $f(z)$ is bounded on the whole complex plane, which is what is needed to conclude that it is constant. And indeed, all nonconstant (and nonbounded) functions of the form $cz^n$ do satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: @GregMartin Just to clarify, is the issue therefore still pending whether it is possible to construct $f(z)$ that satisfies the constraints, but where $f(z)$ does not fit in the pattern $cz^n$?

Comment: @esquire: Any feedback with respect to the answer? Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Let us ignore the trivial case that $f$ is identically zero.

Since $f(0) = 0$ we can choose a radius $R > 0$ such that $f(z)  \ne 0$ for $0 < |z| \le R$, and a real number $M$ with
$$
  0 < M < \min \{ |f(z)| : |z| = R \} \, .
$$
The level set $\{ z : |f (z)| < M \}$ contains the origin and does not intersect the circle $|z| = R$. Since it is connected, it follows that this level set is completely contained in the disk $\{ |z| < R \}$. In other words, we have
$$ \tag{$*$}
 |f(z)| \ge M \text{ for } |z| \ge R \, .
$$

This implies that

- $f$ has no zeros except at the origin, and
- $f$ does *not* have an essential singularity at $\infty$ (e.g. by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem), and is therefore $f$  a polynomial.

Finally, a polynomial which is non-zero except at the origin is necessarily of the form $f(z) = cz^n$.

*Alternative argument,* as suggested by Greg Martin: From $(*)$ we see that $f$ has no zeros except at the origin. It follows that
$$
 f(z) = \frac{z^n}{g(z)}
$$
with $g \in H (\Bbb C)$, $n$ is the multiplicity of the zero of $f$ at the origin. Then $(*)$ gives
$$
 |g(z)| \le \frac{R^n}{M} \text{ for } |z| \ge R \, ,
$$
which implies that $g$ is bounded, and therefore constant (by Liouville's theorem).

Comment: Suggested simplification: write $f(z)=z^n g(z)$ where $g(0)\ne0$. Then $|g(z)| \ge M/R^n$ for $|z|\ge R$, while $|g(z)|$ is bounded away from zero for $|z|\le R$ by continuity. Therefore $1/g(z)$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks for the suggestion. But if Casorati-Weierstrass (which is a consequence of Liouville's theorem) is available then it simply follows from the fact that $f$ omits the disk $B(0, M)$ near infinity. – Those theorems are all closely related.

Comment: For sure. I just thought the OP might benefit from the more hands-on approach.

Comment: @GregMartin: I have added it to the answer, thanks again.